# Adding a global Mongoose Plugin in Nestjs after Mongoose 5.10.5 with built-in type declarations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-plugins

Types are added to Mongoose 5.10.5 and it seems they are different from `@types/mongoose`. Then my code is not running anymore:

```js
import MongooseDeletePlugin from 'mongoose-delete';
...

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(MONGO_URI, {
      connectionFactory: (connection: Connection) => {
        connection.plugin(MongooseDeletePlugin, {

        // ^--- This generates error: "Property 'plugin' does not exist on type 'Connection'."

          overrideMethods: 'all',
          deletedAt: true,
          indexFields: ['deleted'],
        });
        return connection;
      },
    }),
...
```

In Mongoose documentations, [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html#global) is the correct way to add a global plugin. But **How can I add it to the NestJS?**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.plugin(require('./loadedAt'));
```